# Python comparing XML output to a list

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I have an XML that looks something like this:

```
<Import>
  <spId>1234</spId>
  <GroupFlag>false</GroupFlag>
</Import>
```

I want to extract the value of spId and compare it with a list and I have the following script:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml_file = "c:/somefile.xml"

sp_id_list = ['1234']
tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()

for sp_id in root.findall('./spId'):
  if sp_id.text in sp_id_list:
    print sp_id.text
```

This doesn't work for spId (numeric) but works for comparing GroupFlag (string) with a list. Why is this happening and how can I rectify this problem?

Sorry for the stupid question, I am a noob to this.

Comment: With your edit, your code now works flawlessly. Please provide a short, complete program, a short, complete sample input, and the actual and expected output. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for information about how to construct good questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code example works correctly if your XML sample posted here is given as input XML file.

However you want to find all elements. So, I assume that your real document has many `<Import>` items. If a list of items is not wrapped by some parent tag it is not a valid XML. In that case you would have `xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError`.

So, I assume that in your real document `<Import>` is not a root element and `<Import>` elements are somewhere deeper in the document, for example

```
<Parent>
  <Import>
    <spId>1234</spId>
    <GroupFlag>false</GroupFlag>
  </Import>
  <Import>
    <spId>1234</spId>
    <GroupFlag>false</GroupFlag>
  </Import>
</Parent>
```

In that case the search pattern `'./spId'` cannot find those tags, since that pattern matches only direct children of the root element. So, you can use [XPath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath) matching tags all levels beneath or even better pointing direct path from the root to the level where `spId` is located:

```
# all subelements, on all levels beneath the current element
root.findall('.//spId')

# all spId elements directly in Import tags that are directly
# beneath the root element (as in the above XML example)
root.findall('./Import/spId'):
```